# How pagination works which is fetch from api in Nativescript

Tags: javascript, nativescript

I am not getting the concepts of how pagination works in load more requested data from json api. Even i am getting the data of first page but for remaining pages not getting. If I am using the two api for paging and fetching data but still not getting. Any one help me clear this concepts please..

main-view-model.js

```
const httpModule = require("tns-core-modules/http");
var observableModule = require("tns-core-modules/data/observable");
function RegisterViewModel() {
  var viewModel = observableModule.fromObject({
    _sourceDataItems: [],
    initDataItems: function () {
      //This url for the pagination
       var url1 = "https://example.org/api.php?action=query&gcmtitle=Category:xyz&pilimit=max&prop=pageimages&pithumbsize=200&generator=categorymembers&format=json&gcmcontinue=";

       httpModule.getJSON(url1).then((r) => {

         id = r.continue.gcmcontinue
        gcm.push(id)
         console.log(gcm)
         var pageid = [];
         for (var id in r.query.pages) {
           pageid.push(id);
         }
         for (var i = 0; i < pageid.length; i++) {


       if (r.query.pages[pageid[i]].thumbnail == null) {
         let abc = {
           ttt: r.query.pages[pageid[i]].title,
           path1: "~/images/xyz.png"
        }
         this._sourceDataItems.push(abc)
       }
       else {
         let aaa = {
          ttt: r.query.pages[pageid[i]].title,
          path1: r.query.pages[pageid[i]].thumbnail.source
        }
         this._sourceDataItems.push(aaa)
      }

         }

       }, (e) => {
       });

      var gcm = [];

      //This url for the fetching the data on scroll
      for (var i = 0; i < gcm.length; i++) {

        var url2 = "https://example.org/api.php?action=query&gcmtitle=Category:xyz&pilimit=max&prop=pageimages&pithumbsize=200&generator=categorymembers&format=json&gcmcontinue=" + gcm[i];

        httpModule.getJSON(url2).then((r) => {
            id= r.continue.gcmcontinue)
        gcm.push(id)
          console.log(r.continue.gcmcontinue)
          var pageid = [];
          for (var id in r.query.pages) {
            pageid.push(id);
          }
          for (var i = 0; i < pageid.length; i++) {

             //placeholder Image

            if (r.query.pages[pageid[i]].thumbnail == null) {
              let abc = {
                ttt: r.query.pages[pageid[i]].title,
                path1: "~/images/xyz.png"
              }
              this._sourceDataItems.push(abc)
            }
            else {
              let aaa = {
                ttt: r.query.pages[pageid[i]].title,
                path1: r.query.pages[pageid[i]].thumbnail.source
              }
              this._sourceDataItems.push(aaa)
            }

          }

        }, (e) => {
        });
      }

    },

    _DataItems: [],

    addMoreItemsFromSource: function (chunkSize) {
      let newItems = this._sourceDataItems.splice(0, chunkSize);

      this._DataItems = this._DataItems.concat(newItems);

    },
    onLoadMoreItemsRequested: function (args) {
      console.log("---load item called----");
      const that = new WeakRef(this);
      const listView = args.object;
      if (this._sourceDataItems.length > 0) {
        setTimeout(function () {
          that.get().addMoreItemsFromSource(5);
          listView.notifyLoadOnDemandFinished();
        }, 100);
        args.returnValue = true;
      } else {
        args.returnValue = false;

      }
    },
  });
  return viewModel;
}
exports.RegisterViewModel = RegisterViewModel;
```

Even loading of the data is working fine for page one. While passing the gcm continue id it wont take that please help me to clear this concept

Comment: I am new to nativescript please help me

Comment: Simple arrays can not handle change detection, use Observable Array instead.

Comment: Is this logic is correct ? data is not loading can u please help me @manoj

Comment: per page I have only one ID, from this id I need to keep updating the url , How to put single value array then how to fetch that